# Connect with multiple users mysql database in unicenta

Tags: mysql-workbench, multi-user

Please I want to connect two computers using Lan to connect one mysql database... Please can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Set a Static IP Address for the Host SQL Server PC (example 192.168.1.50, a local IP address in your LAN). One of the PCs can be a server or host. The client PCs can stay dynamic.

Open TCP Port `3306` on both PCs (client) firewalls.

On the Client PCs, replace the Host IP Address in place of localhost in the uniCenta Configuration > Database like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabasename` --to-- `jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.50:3306/yourdatabasename`.

The host (server PC) database configuration can stay as `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabasename`. Enter the Username and Password, then click the Test Button to see if a connection is made.

[image: Database configuration Unicenta]

Answer (score 0):

**Server Side :**
First, you have to set static ip on server. eg. 192.168.0.10
create users for each client and give them grant access.
**Client Side :**
set host to jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.10:3306/yourdatabasename
use users created not root.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).